# MS Graph API: How to find out what's a site's template?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

How to find out what's a site's template, using the Graph API? There's an easy way to do this using the REST API, but I couldn't anything in the Graph API which does that.

Basically, I'm looking for the Graph API's equivalent for [Web.WebTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj163655(v=office.15)).

Comment: Are you talking about the Team's site template or communication site templates or custom site template?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation, there seem no such endpoint that could expose the web template.

> Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-beta

BR

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to get the site's Root Web Template is to use the reports endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

There is no easier alternative as far as I know, but in this list you can map site ids and know their templates.